# Adding images from imagelist into a class

Tags: c#, image, class, picturebox, imagelist

I'm a beginner in C# and I have a question regarding about adding images from a imagelist into a class.
The class that I have is used for adding these images, which are "cards" that contain each card's image, suit name, face value, and point value. I have a current in progress working code to add each card's suit name and face value but I'm wondering that for adding the images from a imagelist into the class, is it possible to use a "for" loop to add each image?
Furthermore, I'm trying to add new object instances of a class at least 52 cards...

Below contains my current code:

```
    private void FormShuffleCardDeck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] suitList = new string[4];
        string[] faceList = new string[13];
        int[] pointValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
        string face = "";
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                suitList[i] = i.ToString();
                switch (suitList[i])
                {
                    case "0":
                        suitList[0] = "Hearts";
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        suitList[1] = "Clubs";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        suitList[2] = "Diamonds";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        suitList[3] = "Spades";
                        break;
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++)
                {
                    // face = k.ToString();
                    faceList[k] = k.ToString();
                    switch (faceList[k])
                    {
                        case "0":
                            faceList[0] = "2";
                            break;
                        case "1":
                            faceList[1] = "3";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            faceList[2] = "4";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            faceList[3] = "5";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            faceList[4] = "6";
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            faceList[5] = "7";
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            faceList[6] = "8";
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            faceList[7] = "9";
                            break;
                        case "8":
                            faceList[8] = "10";
                            break;
                        case "9":
                            faceList[9] = "Jack";
                            break;
                        case "10":
                            faceList[10] = "Queen";
                            break;
                         case "11":
                            faceList[11] = "King";
                            break;
                        case "12":
                            faceList[12] = "Ace";
                            break;
                    }
                    cardDeckList[counter] = new PlayingCard(suitList[i], faceList[k], imageListCards.Images[counter], 1);
                    counter++;
                    listBoxOutput.Items.Add(cardDeckList[counter].ToString());
                }
            }
    }
```

Edit: I added a class that I'm working on.

```
 public class PlayingCard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fields: used to store the data about a Playing card (private access for security)
    /// </summary>
    private string  _faceValue;    // face value    
    private string  _suit;         // suit value
    private Image   _cardImage;    // image of card
    private double  _pointValue;   // point Value

    /// <summary>
    /// Properties: used to access the fields (get = read, set = modify or write)
    /// </summary>
    public string Suit
    {
        get { return _suit; }
        set { _suit = value; }
    }
    public string FaceValue
    {
        get { return _faceValue; }
        set { _faceValue = value; }
    }
    public Image CardImage
    {
        get { return _cardImage; }
        set { _cardImage = value; }
    }
    public double PointValue
    {
        get { return _pointValue; }
        set { _pointValue = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The constructor is a special method that instantiates PlayingCard objects (e.g. Ace of Spades).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="suit">The suit of the playing card (e.g. Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds and Spades)</param>
    /// <param name="faceValue">The face value of the playing card (numbers 2-10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace)</param>
    /// <param name="cardImage">The image of the card</param>
    /// <param name="pointValue">The point value of the card</param>
    public PlayingCard(string suit, string faceValue, Image cardImage, double pointValue)
    {
        _suit = suit;
        _faceValue = faceValue;
        _cardImage = cardImage;
        _pointValue = pointValue;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you acrually talking about an [ImageList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes, it is an ImageList.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding your project, you want to create a card deck, 
right?
I thought I design you some little classes that will help you handling your code and idea more easy.

For the beginning I would recommend to start with a class that will fit cards just perfect.

```
public class Card
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int FaceValue { get; set; }
  public int PointValue { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public byte[] image { get; set; }
}
```

And as well your deck. Probably not hard but will be more easy to store your cards or work with more cards without loosing your mind.

```
public class Deck
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

Add `Using System.Linq;` to easily search for cards in your deck with something like:

`Card tmpCard = tmpDeck.Cards.Where(w => w.Name == "MyFavouriteCard").FirstOrDefault();`

That should make it more easy for you to get the cards out of your deck.

Now to save your card Image into your class :)

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image pImage)
{
 ImageConverter tmpConverter = new ImageConverter();
 return (byte[])tmpConverter.ConvertTo(pImage, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

And to convert your saved Image back into a bitmap. As simple as loading it into a byte array:

```
public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] pImage)
{
    MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
    tmpStream.Write(pImage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pImage.Length));
    Bitmap tmpBitmap = new Bitmap(tmpStream, false);
    tmpStream.Dispose();
    return tmpBitmap;
}
```

Load the returned bitmap into a a picture box as example.

Hopefully this will help you a little bit with your project. Or atleast now you know how to get some cards together :)